# python structure for a project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to structure my project, but Im facing some difficulties in importing modules.

This is my project structure, I would like to import `module_1 functions` into `module_2` under `src_1`.

```
src
--src_1
  -- module_1
    --__init__.py
  -- module_2
    --__init__.py
--src_2
  -- module_1
    --__init__.py
--src_3
  -- module_1
    --__init__.py
```

Answer (score 1):

In the init file from module_2:

```
from src.src1 import module_1
```

or

```
import .module_1
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the importing will depend on the the directory from where you are running the code.

In order to import `module_1 functions` into `module_2` under `src_1`, you need to add another `__init__.py` file in `src1`.

Better to add `__init__.py` in all directories if you want to use use methods/classes from different directories.

Something like this:

```
src
  --src_1
    -- module_1
      --__init__.py
    -- module_2
      --__init__.py
    -- __init__.py
  --src_2
    -- module_1
      --__init__.py
    -- __init__.py
  --src_3
    -- module_1
      --__init__.py
    -- __init__.py
  -- __init__.py
```

Comment: apologies, I had already added the _init__.py forgot to mention in my question, I am still not able to import any functions

Comment: From which directory are you trying to run your code ?

Comment: from module_2 ..
i want to import module_1 functions

Comment: Try my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the path to `module_1` into your system path.

Add the below code in your python file in `module_2`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("full path till module_1")
```